# libssh - send request multiple times and read answer from channel

Tags: c++, windows, libssh

I have created one session and one channel. A request (`ssh_channel_request_exec`) is supposed to be sent about every second and I want to read the answer (`ssh_channel_read`) to this request. However, I could not find an example on how to make multiple requests, the api only contains an example on how to make a request, read the answer and close the channel.

When I try requesting and reading from the channel twice in sequence, `ssh_channel_request_exec` returns an error the second time. Is it necessary to open a new channel for each request?

```
int ret = ssh_channel_request_exec(m_channel, request.c_str());
if (ret != SSH_OK)
{
    ssh_channel_close(m_channel);
    ssh_channel_free(m_channel);
    return false;
}

std::stringstream sstream;
nbytes = ssh_channel_read(m_channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
while (nbytes > 0)
{
    sstream.write(buffer, nbytes);
    nbytes = ssh_channel_read(m_channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
}

if (nbytes < 0) // 'nbytes' becomes zero the first time, the channel is not closed the second time!
{
    ssh_channel_close(m_channel);
    ssh_channel_free(m_channel);
    return false;
}

response = sstream.str();
```

The api also contains a `ssh_channel_send_eof` function that is used after reading from the channel in an example. What is good for? The api only says *"Send an end of file on the channel. This doesn't close the channel. You may still read from it but not write."*

A check for `ssh_channel_is_eof` (api: *"Check if remote has sent an EOF"*) shows that the channel is not eof the first time, but the second time it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Non-interactive exec is intended for a single command to be executed and therefore you can run only on in single channel, as visible in the [official documentation](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_command.html).